# Dialer-like app.. force close if piece of code is inserted

Tags: java, android

Trying to develop a dialer-like activity. This is the code I have so far below...

```
public class Dial extends Activity implements OnClickListener {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dial);


    Button pb1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pb1);
    Button pb2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pb2);
    Button pb3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pb3);
    Button pb4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pb4);
    Button pb5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pb5);
    Button pb6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pb6);
    Button pb7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pb7);
    Button pb8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pb8);
    Button pb9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pb9);
    Button pb0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pb0);
    Button pbstar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pbstar);
    Button pbhash = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pbhash);
    Button pbcall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pbcall);


    pb1.setOnClickListener(this);
    pb2.setOnClickListener(this);
    pb3.setOnClickListener(this);
    pb4.setOnClickListener(this);
    pb5.setOnClickListener(this);
    pb6.setOnClickListener(this);
    pb7.setOnClickListener(this);
    pb8.setOnClickListener(this);
    pb9.setOnClickListener(this);
    pb0.setOnClickListener(this);
    pbstar.setOnClickListener(this);
    pbhash.setOnClickListener(this);



}


@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{

    TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

      int id =  (v.getId());

      if (id == R.id.pb1){        
            text.append("1");
      }

      if (id == R.id.pb2){        
          text.append("2");
  }
      if (id == R.id.pb3){        
          text.append("3");
  }
      if (id == R.id.pb4){        
          text.append("4");
  }
      if (id == R.id.pb5){        
          text.append("5");
  }
      if (id == R.id.pb6){        
          text.append("6");
  }
      if (id == R.id.pb7){        
          text.append("7");
  }
      if (id == R.id.pb8){        
          text.append("8");
  }
      if (id == R.id.pb9){        
          text.append("9");
  }
      if (id == R.id.pb0){        
          text.append("0");
  }


}

}
```

With this code, the app force closes. However, if i remove this part:

```
Button pb1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pb1);
Button pb2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pb2);
Button pb3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pb3);
Button pb4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pb4);
Button pb5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pb5);
Button pb6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pb6);
Button pb7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pb7);
Button pb8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pb8);
Button pb9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pb9);
Button pb0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pb0);
Button pbstar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pbstar);
Button pbhash = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pbhash);
Button pbcall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pbcall);


pb1.setOnClickListener(this);
pb2.setOnClickListener(this);
pb3.setOnClickListener(this);
pb4.setOnClickListener(this);
pb5.setOnClickListener(this);
pb6.setOnClickListener(this);
pb7.setOnClickListener(this);
pb8.setOnClickListener(this);
pb9.setOnClickListener(this);
pb0.setOnClickListener(this);
pbstar.setOnClickListener(this);
pbhash.setOnClickListener(this);
```

the app launches fine but does nothing (because there's no onClickListener.) Is there an error lying in those declaration lines? I've tried changing them but still nothing...what i want basically is when you press the button, it displays (in a textview) the number assigned to it...What can I do to solve this problem? I'm sorry if its a beginner question but I'm now starting out and I would really like to sort this problem out.

LOGCAT:

```
11-06 14:42:04.358: I/dalvikvm-heap(1658): Grow heap (frag case) to 52.477MB for 10074256-byte         allocation
11-06 14:42:04.518: I/dalvikvm-heap(1658): Grow heap (frag case) to 62.144MB for 10126096-byte allocation
11-06 14:42:04.668: I/dalvikvm-heap(1658): Grow heap (frag case) to 71.617MB for 9970576-byte allocation
11-06 14:42:10.144: W/dalvikvm(1658): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception  (group=0x417e5898)
11-06 14:42:10.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1658): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 14:42:10.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1658): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.devon.carmate/com.devon.carmate.Dial}: java.lang.ClassCastException:  android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
11-06 14:42:10.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
11-06 14:42:10.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
11-06 14:42:10.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java)
11-06 14:42:10.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
11-06 14:42:10.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
11-06 14:42:10.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
11-06 14:42:10.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
11-06 14:42:10.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 14:42:10.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-06 14:42:10.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
11-06 14:42:10.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
11-06 14:42:10.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:115)
11-06 14:42:10.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-06 14:42:10.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1658): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
11-06 14:42:10.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at com.devon.carmate.Dial.onCreate(Dial.java:23)
11-06 14:42:10.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
11-06 14:42:10.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
11-06 14:42:10.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     ... 13 more
```

Comment: The only reason I see from this code is that at least one of those `id`s are incorrect where you are initializing a `Button` or other `View`. Double check that you are using the same `id`s that are in `dial.xml`. And if you post the logcat from the crash we will know exactly where the issue is, most likely. It also could be a casting issue but the logcat will know.

Comment: Are you using a Button widget instead of ImageButton in your XML layout?

Comment: Okay i found the problem..I was declaring a Button instead of an ImageButton..but your request for the logcat made me realise it..thank you very much!!

Comment: You're welcome. I have posted an answer after seeing your logcat. I am also going to update with a suggestion on the `listener`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem

```
11-06 14:42:10.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1658): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.devon.carmate/com.devon.carmate.Dial}: java.lang.ClassCastException:  android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
```

you have your `Button`s declared as `ImageButton`s in your xml but trying to cast to `Button` in Java. Either change them to `Button` in your xml or change them to `ImageButton` in Java F

For exmample, instead of

```
 Button pb1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pb1);
```

change it to

```
 ImageButton pb1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pb1);
```

**Different implementation of listener**

Instead of declaring all of your `Button`s and assigning `listener`s in Java, you can do it in xml. This works nicely in a situation like this where all of the `Button`s use the same `onClick()` event. This will clean up your code in Java, make it more readable, and reduce the risk of errors, IMHO. All you need to do is assign the `onClick` property for each `Button` or `ImageButton` in your xml to some function like this

```
<Button 
    ...
    android:onClick="someFunction"/>
```

the "..." above is where your other properties are. Then in Java you don't need to add `implements OnClickListener` and you don't need all of the declarations or setting the `listener`. Just define your function according to the proper rules

1. Must be public
2. Must take one parameter which is a View

so something like

```
public void someFunction(View v) //just use the same name as in your xml
{
    int id = v.getId();
    if (id == R.id.pb1){        
        text.append("1");
    }

    if (id == R.id.pb2){        
      text.append("2");
     // etc
}
```

You could also use a `switch` statement on the `id` which will make it more readable, IMHO.

You can read more about doing it this way in the [Button Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)